# How to avoid full table scan when using OR operator on an Index

Tags: mysql, join, optimization

Essentially, I want to get intersection between 2 tables based on matching IDs with the option of wildcard '*' to return all IDs:

> Select * from A a inner join B b on b.id = a.id or b.id = '*'

Table A is fairly large (10 M rows), and I have setup the `id` to be index already.

Because of `OR`, index `id` is not used, and it does a full scan (Takes 20 secs).

If I don't allow the wildcard:

> Select * from A a inner join B b on b.id = a.id

It uses `id` index and takes only 300 ms

Edit:

By separating into 2 select with Union helped. Detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901791/is-having-an-or-in-an-inner-join-condition-a-bad-idea

Comment: can't you split your query in 2 rather than using or?

Comment: What is the estimated selectivity of the index on `b.id` with and without `or b.id = '*'`?  It should be able to use the index with the OR, but if there are a lot of rows with `b.id = '*'`, it might opt for the full scan because of a low estimated selectivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common trick for optimizing `OR` is to turn it into `UNION`:

```
( SELECT * FROM A JOIN B USING(id) WHERE condition_1 )
UNION DISTINCT
( SELECT * FROM A JOIN B USING(id) WHERE condition_2 )
```

(I'm with Jack on being confused on what you really wanted, so I avoided spelling out the details of the conditions.)

Be sure to include index(es) that let the queries start with the conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Reformatting your query slightly we have:

```
select * from A a 
inner join B b on 
    b.id = a.id     -- condition 1
    or
    b.id = '*'      -- condition 2
```

Consider how this will match rows from B with rows from A:

1. If there is a row in B with an `id` that matches the `id` in A, include that row along with the row from A.
2. If there is any row in B with an `id` that matches '*', include that row along with the row from A.

Condition #2 means that if there are **any** rows in B with an `id` of '*', then **all** of the rows in A must be included, because they all match those rows in B.

This also means that **every** row in B that has an `id` of '*' matches **every** row in A.

Is that really what you want? If so then there is no way to avoid a full scan because every row in A is included.